# What is the use of validation data?

Tags: tensorflow

I am following this tutorial to build a classifier:
https://towardsdatascience.com/a-simple-cnn-multi-image-classifier-31c463324fa
In this part of the code:

```
# loading up our datasets
train_data_dir = ‘data/train’ 
validation_data_dir = ‘data/validation’ 
test_data_dir = ‘data/test
```

I understand what is the use of train data, what is the use of the test data, however I cannot figure out what is the use of validation data... I googled it and I found this tutorial: https://machinelearningmastery.com/difference-test-validation-datasets/
but I got more confused. What does it mean by saying the following??

**Validation Dataset:** The sample of data used to provide an unbiased evaluation of a model fit on the training dataset while tuning model hyperparameters. The evaluation becomes more biased as skill on the validation dataset is incorporated into the model configuration.

What is the purpose of validation data anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validation data set is used to measure how well the model generalizes when applied to new data that it hasn't seen before. Take the example of a math teacher that is teaching arithmetic to grade school students. Ideally, the final exam should have problems on it that are of the same kind as the ones given in the homework but that are new problems with different numbers in them to ensure that the teacher can assess whether the students really learned how to add, subtract, multiply, and divide vs. simply regurgitated memorized answers to the problems previously seen in the assigned homework. Stated another way, the purpose of keeping a separate validation data set consisting of data that was not used in training the model is to avoid overfitting the model to the training set.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to avoid overfitting, or in other words learning more about *specific examples* than *general characteristics*.   If you just tested your model on the training data, it could easily just learn the (lets say) 1000 cat pics you wanted to distinguish from the 100 dog pics, by 'memorizing' those 100 pics - a CNN could easily have an amount of memory in its weights equivalent to 100 pics. And obviously its not the entire pic that needs to be memorized but only something that distinguishes those particular cat pics from those particular dog pics. This can happen anytime the number of free params in the model can compete with the amount of information in the training set. To avoid this the test should be on another set of data, the validation set. But the same thing can happen with the validation set ! If the network is set to minimize error on the validation set that's what it will do, and thus the validation set may itself become overfit. So a third test is used (in principle only once, to avoid yet again overfitting on this data, and so on ) for final evaluation.